# Missing values from Ordered set in C++11 Custom objects

Tags: c++, c++11, set

I am trying to have elements in the SET [ordered SET C++11] first ordered by the double value and then ordered by the no of set bits in the set_type data structure. I have created a custom comparator but its not inserting the elements for which the no of set bits are same. However, if I dont sort the elements on the number of set bits in the set_type it gives the correct output.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <cstdint>

typedef uint64_t set_type;

struct setNode {
    std::pair<double,set_type> data;
};

unsigned int bitCount (set_type value) {
    unsigned int count = 0;
    while (value > 0) {           // until all bits are zero
        if ((value & 1) == 1)     // check lower bit
            count++;
        value >>= 1;              // shift bits, removing lower bit
    }
    return count;
}


struct CompClass {
    bool operator()(const setNode& lhs, const setNode& rhs) const
    {

        if (lhs.data.first == rhs.data.first) {
            int n1 = bitCount(lhs.data.second);
            int n2 = bitCount(rhs.data.second);
            return n1 > n2;
        }
        return lhs.data.first < rhs.data.second;
    }
};


int main() {


    set_type x = 15;    

    std::set<setNode,CompClass> Q;
    std::set<setNode,CompClass>::iterator it_SetNode;
    it_SetNode = Q.begin();

    Q.insert(setNode{std::make_pair(100.0,0)});
    Q.insert(setNode{std::make_pair(100.0,10)});
    Q.insert(setNode{std::make_pair(100.0,1)});
    Q.insert(setNode{std::make_pair(100.0,15)});
    Q.insert(setNode{std::make_pair(100.0,7)});
    Q.insert(setNode{std::make_pair(100.0,9)});
    Q.insert(setNode{std::make_pair(100.0,11)});

    for (auto x:Q) {
        std::cout << "X:" << x.data.first << "   Y:" << x.data.second << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}


Expected output:
X:100   Y:15
X:100   Y:11
X:100   Y:7
X:100   Y:9
X:100   Y:10
X:100   Y:1
X:100   Y:0
```

But its giving:

```
X:100   Y:15
X:100   Y:7
X:100   Y:10
X:100   Y:1
X:100   Y:0
```

Comment: I believe this line is wrong: `return lhs.data.first < rhs.data.second;` You probably wanted to compare `first` to `first`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both the numbers 7 and 11, in binary, have the same number of 1 bits: 4+2+1, and 8+2+1.

Therefore, your comparator compares {100.0,7} and {100.0,11}) as equal values, and because `std::set` only allows unique values, and these values are considered equal, the duplicate value does not get inserted into your set.

Comment: I was wondering the same, is there a way to get around this. Or I will have to look for another data structure like multi-set?

Comment: A multiset will allow you to have {100.0,7} and {100.0,7} values in the container. If this is what you want, fine. If not, try finishing the following sentence for me: "my std::pair comparator compares std::pair.first; if they're the same value my comparator compares the number of bits in std::pair.second; if they're the same value my comparator compares ____".

Comment: compares the std::pair.second (its decimal value). As its guaranteed to be unique[in my data].

Comment: Perfect way to give hints. Giving you an virtual standing ovation. Freaking thing disturbed my weekend.